# Game crashes when player touches bouncy pad

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

this is gdscript and i've called my player to increase it's velocity. If there's any other way to implement this?

```
extends Area2D

@onready var Main_char = %CharacterBody2D
func _on_body_entered(body):
    if(body.name == "player"):
        Main_char.velocity.y = -800
```

the code is supposed to change the velocity of the player by 800 when it touches the bouncy pad

Comment: What error shows up  in the console? How is your tree structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change `%CharacterBody2D` to `%player`. When you getting the node it must be named exactly like in the scene tree.

Also, I recommend to change names. Node's name usually capitalized (change `player` to `Player` in the scene tree). Variables should be lowercased. Note that you can compare `body` right away with `main_char` variable. If you apply this changes full Bouncy Pad code will be this:

```
extends Area2D

@onready var main_char = %Player

func _on_body_entered(body):
    if(body == main_char):
        body.velocity.y = -800
```

I have tested this code and it works

[image: Player jumbs on Bouncy Pad]